# I need some help to make a dynamic input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I´m making an inventory control program for a veterinary, but in one of the windows to control the stock provider I have a select input and the idea is, when I select that the purchase is for credit, a new input will appear (type date) to select when the invoice payment term expires. I've tried whit jQuery and javaScript, but it still not working, any idea?

This is the form:

```
<form method="post" action="guardaArt.php">
                                            <tr> <td>Codigo</td> <td><input type=text name="codigo"></td> </tr>
                                            <tr> <td>Nombre</td> <td><input type=text name="nombre"></td> </tr>
                                            <tr> <td>Gravado o Exento</td> <td><select name="select">
                                                                                <option value="1" selected>Gravado</option>
                                                                                <option value="2">Exento</option>
                                                                            </select></td> </tr>
                                            <tr> <td>Precio de Compra</td> <td><input type=text name="precioComp"></td> </tr>
                                            <tr> <td>Precio de Venta</td> <td><input type=text name="precioVent"></td> </tr>
                                            <tr> <td>Precio de Venta por Unidad</td> <td><input type=text name="precioUni"></td> </tr>
                                            <tr> <td>Contenido</td> <td><input type=text name="cont"></td> </tr>
                                            <tr> <td>Codigo del Proveedor</td> <td><input type=text name="codProv"></td> </tr> 
                                            <tr> <td>Usos</td> <td><input type=text name="usos"></td> </tr>
                                            <tr> <td>A Crédito</td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <select name="tipo" id="mylist">
                                                        <option value="0" selected>No</option>
                                                        <option value="1">Sí</option>
                                                    </select>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr> <td>Vencimiento</td><td></td>
                                            </tr> 
                                            <tr> <td align= "center"><input type='submit' name='articulo' value='Guardar Artículo' formaction='guardaArt.php'/></td><tr> <td align= "center"><input type='submit' name='articulos' value='Guardar Artículo a Crédito' formaction='ing_art.php'/></td> </tr>
                                        </form>}
```

**and the jQuery**

```
<script>
            $('#mylist').change(function(){
                if( $(this).val() == '1'){
                    $('body').append('<input id="myInput" name="vence" type="date" />');
                }
                else{
                    $('#myInput').remove();
                }
            });
    </script>
```

Comment: What's not working? I see it working as expected :)

Comment: It's working here : https://jsfiddle.net/bilelh/f29tpbou/ ! The only thing I changed for validation is a missing closing </tr>